# error: can't allocate region in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm adding objects into mutable array whenever a row of `UIPickerView` is get selected by calling this method-

```
-(void)setScheduleStartDate:(NSString *)dateStr
{
    [scheduleDatesArray removeAllObjects];
    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateFormat = @"d MMMM yyyy";
    scheduleStartDate = [df dateFromString:dateStr];

    /******* getting array of schedule dates     ***********/

    NSDate* scheduleEndDate = [scheduleStartDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*28*6]; // add six month (of 28 days) in schedule start date
    double endMS = [scheduleEndDate timeIntervalSinceDate:scheduleStartDate];

    for (double i =0; i < endMS; i = (i + 60*60*24*14)) {

        [scheduleDatesArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:i]];
    }
}
```

After several calls to this method my crashes with this error message

```
malloc: *** mmap(size=627101696) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

by setting break point in `malloc_error_break` my app breaks in for loop( where I'm adding objects to array). But I'm unable to find the problem, I've searched over google for same problems but still no luck.

Can any one help me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I assume `scheduleDatesArray` is a `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: And are you using ARC?

Comment: Yes it is NSMutableArray and allocated as scheduleDatesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0]; and i'm using ARC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really not make date calculation based on some assumption that a month is 28 days or even that [a minute is 60 seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second).

Instead of `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` use `NSCalendar`'s `dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:`

```
NSDateComponents *sixMonthComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
sixMonthComponents.month = 6;

NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate* scheduleEndDate = [currentCalendar dateByAddingComponents:sixMonthComponents toDate:scheduleStartDate options:0];
```

**EDIT**: From what I understand, you want to add a time interval to your array for every ~14 days (a half month as you defined a month to be 28 days). To be more robust, I'd do something like this (not tested but should work, let me know):

```
// We increment i with the total interval between the two dates (endMS) divided by 12 (6 months * 2 times per month)
for (double i = 0; i < endMS; i += (endMS / 12) {
    [scheduleDatesArray addObject:@(i)];
}
```

*Side note*: `[NSNumber numberWithDouble:i]` [can be written `@(i)`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Comment: yes I'm adding  time interval to my array, but 14 is just an example  it will vary to 1, 4, 7, 14, 28 days according to user selection.

Comment: Ok i got the solution, in the for loop i was using a ivar(14 was just an example) to increase value of i and some times ivar get assigned to -1 and loop goes infinite(my mistake)..i'm accepting your answer for make my code more reliable.